# HTML/Javascript - How to realize a dynamic table with images

Tags: javascript, html-table

I want to have a table that has 4 rows and a variable number of columns. The cells of the table should contain images. And I want to add images dynamically. How do I do this? Is there a tutorial somewhere? I haven't been able to find a suitable tutorial.

Comment: What's dynamic about it? When is the table created? How are additional columns added - is it in response to user input, part of a loop? Where do the images come from? How is the image for each cell selected?

Comment: You're also unlikely to find a tutorial specifically about a dynamic table that contains images, though you might. You'd be better off thinking about how you want it to work, identifying the steps you need to implement to get what you want, and then looking for tutorials that teach you how to do those things. If, for example, you want to add a new cell to the last row when the user clicks a button, the first thing you'll need to learn is how to run code in response to a button being clicked on.

Comment: So the answer depends on what you mean by "dynamic". Is it the way that the javascript gets the number of images, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like [this](http://www.mountaindragon.com/html/tables2.htm) ??

Above link has a comprehensive tutorial to add images in table cells. You should work on it to customise the table as per your need.

I couldn't understand how you want javascript to add images to the table dynamically. But here is a small example to have javascript to add images into a table cell.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function AddImage()
{
  document.getElementById("cell").innerHTML = "<img src='YourImageFile.png'>";
}

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="AddImage();">

<table>
<td id="cell">your image will appear here</td>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Good luck